# fixing margins from navbar

Tags: html, css

In my recent project, I adjust the style for this header:

```
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="title">Loja</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right">
  <li><a href="#" class="user">username</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

as that:

```
header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  width:100%;
}

header:after{
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/ch6gtj3p/7/

but with this, I got a small space between the edge of the browser's window and the navbar. What I can do to remove this space?

Comment: you need to reset browser default settings : `body {
  margin: 0;
}`

Comment: Remove default body margin. `body {margin: 0;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the default `margin` and `padding` of the `<html>` and `<body>` element:

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

**Working solution:** https://jsfiddle.net/ch6gtj3p/8/